# OperationalError - cursor "_django_curs_<id>" does not exist for edit and add form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

On accessing a url to add or edit form, which would render a template to edit the form gives the error - OperationalError at /edf/data_asset_format_edit//

I tried running makemigrations and migrate, even after that i get the above error. I tried creating a new object for the same model from shell (python manage.py shell), it works.

OperationalError at /edf/data_asset_format_edit/466/
cursor "_django_curs_140026377369344_10" does not exist

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    https:///edf/data_asset_format_edit/466/

Django Version: 1.11

Exception Type: OperationalError

Exception Value:
cursor "_django_curs_140026377369344_10" does not exist
Exception Location: /opt/edfprod/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql, line 880

Python Executable:  /opt/edfprod/python/bin/python

Python Version: 2.7.11

Traceback:

File "/opt/edfprod/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/opt/edfprod/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/edfprod/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/edftest/test2/ui/dna_django/edf/views.py" in data_asset_format_edit
  726.     return render(request, 'edf/data_asset_format_edit.html', {'form': form})

File "/opt/edfprod/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/opt/edfprod/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

Views -

```
def data_asset_format_edit(request, edf_data_asset_format_id):
   ...
   ...
  pa = EdfProviderDataAssetVw.objects.get(p_data_asset_id=data_asset_format.data_asset_id)
    form = EdfDataAssetFormatForm(instance=data_asset_format, data_asset=daf_data_asset, initial={'provider_name': pa.provider_name, 'provider_id': pa.provider_id, 'p_data_asset_name': pa.p_data_asset_name, 'p_data_asset_id': pa.p_data_asset_id, 'updated_by': User.objects.get(username=request.user)})

return render(request, 'edf/data_asset_format_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

I dont understand what is causing this error.